# NetBeans: display only icons on window title

Tags: netbeans, icons, title

i've got 1024x600 resolution and cant afford a lot of windows opened in NetBeans.
Is there a way to display only icons in window title?
For example:

Icon1 Projects

Icon2 Files

Icon3 Services
...

Can it be like:

Icon1

Icon2

Icon3
?

Comment: Which version of windows? is it `windows 7`?

Comment: IF its windows 7, refer this http://www.pcworld.com/article/235112/Icons.html

Comment: For windows XP you can try this trick http://www.askvg.com/get-windows-7-iconized-icon-only-taskbar-feature-in-windows-xp-and-vista/

Comment: Log1c, sorry, but it is not what im asking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not. You may want to start NetBeans with `--fontsize 10` or similar to save space. Also change toolbar to use small icons (right click in empty toolbar area to display its menu) or completely hide all its components. If I remember correctly they may have been a special switch to merge menu and toolbar to save space but you would have to scan sources and it is likely broken now.

Comment: i appreciate your answer. Though fontsize is not a good idea for me